# Angular UI Bootstrap - Carousel directive - Animate CSS Provider unknown

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to use the carousel directive, and am getting two errors.

**First error:**

```
Unknown provider: $animateCssProvider <- $animateCss <- .item-animation
```

**Second error:**

```
TypeError: $animate.on is not a function
```

**package.json:**

```
"bootstrap": "*",
"angular": ">=1.4.0",
"grunt-angular-templates": "1.0.4",
"angular-animate": "1.4.0",
"angular-translate": "^2.7.0",
"angular-ui-bootstrap": "^1.2.4",
"checklist-model": "*",
"numeral": "*",
"angular-numeraljs": "^1.0"
```

**controller:**

```
var estateCarouselController = presentation.controller('estateCarouselController',['$scope',function($scope){
$scope.myInterval = 3000;
$scope.noWrapSlides = false;
$scope.active = 0;
$scope.slides = [
    {
        image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'
    },
    {
        image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food'
    },
    {
        image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports'
    },
    {
        image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people'
    }
];
}
```

**markup:**

```
<uib-carousel active="0" interval="myInterval">
        <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" index="$index">
            <img ng-src="{[{slide.image}]}" style="margin:auto;" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>Slide {[{$index+1}]}</h4>
            </div>
        </uib-slide>
    </uib-carousel>
```

**NOTE:** Delimiter is to avoid conflict with Twig.

**EDIT:** Module declaration.

```
var presentation = angular.module('presentation', ['ngNumeraljs','apiModule',"checklist-model",'ngAnimate',"ui.bootstrap"]);
```

Comment: make sure that you have the correct dependencies in your module declaration

angular.module("app", ["shared", "ui.bootstrap"]);

Comment: As @fireydude said, and don't forget ngAnimate, too. It's likely the `$animate` from `ngAnimate` is not available.

Comment: What is shared? Is that a dependency created by ngAnimate? I am ofc including ngAnimate in my module. Are the versions ok?

Comment: you also need ui.bootstrap.  You should post your module declaration

Comment: Edited for more clarification